# IIS 8 Configure page with subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, iis, subdomain, subdirectory

currently I have setup my page in IIS. It can be accessed over the IP address of the server only (so something like: "127.0.0.1"). What I want to do is move the page to a sub-directory, so that if someone uses the IP addess only, he won't get to the page (404 error). I would like the page to be accessible by using something like this: "127.0.0.1/someName". This should let the user access the default page, as it is now. Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Virtual Directories](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Right click the site, and click Add Virtual Directory. Give it a name (this will be the sub directory name).

Then, just make sure your virtual directory has the correct default page configured. For example, if MyPage.aspx should be the default, then put it in as the default document.

Comment: If I use Web Deploy in Visual Studio, how do I tell it to publish the page into the Virtual Dirctory?

Comment: @Cleo What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I believe when setting up your publish profile, just do www.mysite.com/MyApplication where MyApplication is the name of your virtual directory.

Comment: Thx, that did the job! Here is what I did:  
  `- create a new page in iis  
  - add a new virtual directory to the page  
- right-click the virtual directory and select "Convert to application"  
- in Visual Studio under "Publish" (Web Deploy), use the correct path to your virtual directory in "Websitename". Under "Server", just enter the IP of your target server.`